# ASP.NET validator one behind with code generated form

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, telerik

I have created server created forms using Telerik AJAX controls with a submit button that does a post (no click event).  My forms use validators which work fine except they happen on the next post after the field validation error.

If I make an email field empty which the code logic catches and returns an error. Submit again and the email required field validator works to catch the error before the code.  Now put valid data and submit and the last empty field validator error with appears again. Submit the good data a second time and it updates.

Also, if I produce my own validator error then the validators work fine. I have validator code for required checkboxes. If a missing check happens I call

```
ValidatorError.Display(Page, message);
```

which causes the subsequent

```
Page.Validate(FormEntryBase.VALIDATION_GROUP);
```

to properly validate required fields in current submit.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {


            localValidationError = theForm.CustomValidateForm(Request.Form);
            if (localValidationError) {
                validateErrorList = form.validateErrorList;

                // get local valiation error put into validation summary error list
                if (validateErrorList != null) {
                    foreach (string message in validateErrorList) {
                        ValidatorError.Display(Page, message);
                    }
                }
            }
            Page.Validate(FormEntryBase.VALIDATION_GROUP);

            if (!Page.IsValid ) {
                return;
            }
```

Validator errors the code does not catch are not caught on an initial submit which lets bad data in.

I have another web form that uses the click method and only uses Page.IsValid which works fine.

Very strange behaviour, some sort life cycle problem probably.

Comment: It is a post, not an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

With some luck, I figured out a solution by adding a click event in code. To add a click event, first I added the RadButton to my form creation code be accessed in the aspx.cs.

```
RadButton button = new RadButton();
button.ValidateRequestMode = ValidateRequestMode.Enabled;
button.ValidationGroup = VALIDATION_GROUP;
button.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
theForm.updateButton = button;
```

In the aspx.cs Page_Load I added the click method to the button.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ...
  theForm = group.GetJoinForm();
  theForm.updateButton.Click  += new EventHandler(UpdateButton_Click);
  ...

void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Page.Validate(FormEntryBase.VALIDATION_GROUP);
  if (!Page.IsValid) {
    return;
  }
  ... most of page load code moved here
```

These three steps fixed my validate delay problems and all my forms now validate quite well.